# Javascript add date and time to mailto subject link

Tags: javascript, html

I want to put the current date and time into the subject of a `mailto:` link.
Here's my code so far:

(I can't paste my code for some reason. Ill use pastebin)
http://pastebin.com/FUwZrBwv
How, in javascript, can I find the `subject =` line and add to that?

```js
var d = new Date(86400000);
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = d;
```

```html
  Problem? <a href="mailto:[redacted]@gmail.com?subject=ServerError">Click!</a>
<div id="timedowndiv">
  <p>Redirecting in  3 seconds . . .
</div>
```

Comment: One problem is that there is no element in the page with an ID of "demo".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use sth similar to,

```
<a href="javascript:var date = new Date(); window.open('mailto:test@example.com?subject='+date +'&body=body');">test</a>
```

Comment: Is there a way to add this to Wordpress/Elementor click to links?

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would do it:

```
<a id="mail1" onclick="setMail1Href()">Click</a>

<script>
    function setMail1Href(){
        var linkTemplate="mailto:leeeyecard@gmail.com?subject=ServerError at (DATE)";
        var mail1=Document.getElementById("mail1");
        mail1.setAttribute("href",linkTemplate.replace("(DATE)",new Date().toDateString());
        return true;
    }
</script>
```

The `onclick="setMail1Href()"` in the anchor causes the function to be called when the link is clicked. The function uses the DOM API to access the anchor and set it's href to `linkTemplate` with `(DATE)` replaced with the current date. It then returns true so that the link will be followed.

Comment: upvote for your username (ok, and also for your answer)